# Condition for the mean to be larger than the median

Tags: probability, statistics, means, median

I was wondering whether there is a condition, phrased in probability terms, for a median to be less or equal to the mean in a sample of positive numbers?

If $X$ is the positive Random variable corresponding to the values in the sample, can we give a condition for example on the variance of $X$ for this to be true?

This comes from my presumption that samples of weight, height , I.Q, and others should satisfy this property, and wondered whether one can justify it by showing the sample satisfies certain conditions. I have not dealt that much with quantiles, but I suspect this question was probably posed and answered long ago.

I would appreciate any insight on the matter.

Comment: Many random variables occuring in reality are in good approximation normal distributed. I do not know whether such a distribution satisfies your property. The IQ for example can safely assumed to be nearly normal distributed, whether the value allows conclusions to the intelligence of the corresponding person is something else.

Comment: There is a proof by Mallows which concludes that $|\mu - m|\leq \sigma$, where $\mu$ denotes the mean, $m$ the median and $\sigma$ the standard deviation. You can also find and upper bound on the median by considering Markov’s Inequality $$\frac12=P(x\geq m)\leq\frac{E[X]}m\implies m\leq 2E[X]$$, which is probably not the best bound.